# jade uploading html page exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have 2 different flask programms on python3 and they work with different pages. Separately 1 from another they run beautifull. The first is html page with some d3.js content the 2 is .jade page with JQuery. I am trying to load html content from .jade page like this:

```
script(src="../../static/js/jquery.js")
div(id="block")
script.
    $('#block').load('http://localhost:8025')
```

localhost:8025 is an adress of 1 html page that is already running.But my content not loaded. I meet this exception:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8025/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://0.0.0.0:5000' is therefore not allowed access.

After searching for an answer - I add a Google Chrome extention that did't solve my problem. I'm new in JS and Jade, can you give me some advises(probably better with code) how to upload content?

Comment: Are you making the request from the same domain? If so, use a relative path. If not, you need to add CORS headers to the response

Comment: I am making request from localhost, but from different ports. They are not in 1 package and relative pass u meen something like that: "../../../../../template/layout.html" ? They are processing with flask and if I will open localhost:8025/layout.html ill meet an exception

Comment: mb CORS you meen smthing like that: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Different ports is your problem. JS can only make AJAX requests to the current domain (down to the port and protocol) unless the third party domain expressly permits it using CORS headers. If you're using NodeJS, I'd suggest googling for 'How to enable CORS in nodeJS'

Comment: Have made this with flask-cors, but it can upload only 1 page - without information from sources like data.json. How I can load full resource with multiple pages from 1 port to another?